# Struct in C misunderstanding

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to understand the concept of struct and typedef in C. SO i created this simple program, but for some reason it is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct testT{

    int number;

} testT;

int main()
{
    testT.number=10;

    printf("%d", testT->number);
}
```

However, it is giving me 
error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
Why is this showing up?

Thanks

Comment: Also I think I read that typedef struct {} is a C++ syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`testT` is a type, just like `int`, you need to use a variable:

```
testT t;
t.number=10;
printf("%d", t.number);
```

Also note that you should use dot operator `.` because the arrow operator `->` is used on a pointer to `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of your struct. You've defined it, but you need to instantiate it.

```
testT mytestT;
mytestT.number=10;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `struct <name>` and `typedef <type> <name>` only define types. You have to actually allocate memory to hold an instance of that type:

```
int main()
{
  struct testT a;
  a.number=10;

  printf("%d", a.number);
}
```

Also you are misusing the `->` operator. This is only useful with pointers to structs.

```
int main()
{
  struct testT a;
  struct testT *b = &a;
  a.number=10;

  printf("%d", b->number);
}
```

`b->number` is equivalent to `(*b).number`;

Answer (score 1):

No, `typedef struct xxx { ... } yyy;` is not 'a C++ syntax', it is a correct C syntax.

What you are doing here is defining a type called `testT` which represents a `struct testT` being a struct containing a field of type `int` called `number`.

What you need to do to use this type is declare a variable of that type:

```
int main(void)
{
  testT variable;

  variable.number = 10;
  printf("%d\n", variable.number);
}
```

`->` notation is used to replace `(*).`. For example :

```
//With variable declared like this :
testT *variable;
//You can write:
variable->number
//Or:
(*variable).number
```

Answer (score 0):

`testT` is a type. First declare a variable of type `testT`

```
testT t;
```

And do not forget to change

```
printf("%d", testT->number);
```

to

```
printf("%d", t.number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct testT {
    int number;
} testT;
```

Defines a type called `testT`, which when used like so:

```
testT aTestStruct;
```

Is functionally equivalent to (an anonymous struct type):

```
struct { int number } aTestStruct;
```

The *typdef* just allows us to save ourselfs from having to repeat the anonymous struct declaration syntax of `struct { ... }` each time.